# using annotations with struts 2 in jboss not finding actions

Tags: jboss, struts2, annotations, action, convention

The application is using Jboss and has an ear file which contains an war file and a jar file.  The war contians all our web pages.  The action classes which I have annotated are in the jar file that is in the ear.  From my googleing I have setup my struts.xml file with the following constants:

```
<constant name="struts.convention.action.fileProtocols" value="ear,jar,vfsfile,vfszip" />
<constant name="struts.convention.action.disableJarScanning" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.convention.action.includeJars" value=".*/lightspeed.*?jar(!/)?,.*/lightspeed*?jar(!/)?,.*lightspeed.*?jar(!/)?,.*lightspeed*?jar(!/)?" />
```

Jboss container starts up fine, but my action is not loaded.  I have downloaded the source for the convention plugin to see what it is using to find the action classes and it seems to only look at the war file for action classes when it scans.  Is there a way to get it to look in the jar file that contains the actions class when it scans foe the annotated action classes?

file structure:
-application.ear
  |--application.war
  |--aplication_logic_actions.jar *<--- this contains the action classes which are annotated*

I have debugged the code for the convention plugin and here is where I see my problem.  In the *PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder* class and the *buildUrlSet()* method it has this line of code:

```
UrlSet urlSet = new UrlSet(classLoaderInterface, this.fileProtocols);
```

after this code I get about 200 + urls.  It then goes through this code:

```
if (excludeParentClassLoader) {
```

This condiftion block removes all my urls since they are all from jboss I guess and I have *excludeParentClassLoader* set to true.  It then hits this code:

```
urlSet = urlSet.includeClassesUrl(classLoaderInterface);
```

after this I get one url in my urlset:

> file:/C:/evolution/trunk/powersports/jboss/server/dms/deploy/http-invoker.sar/invoker.war=file:/C:/evolution/trunk/powersports/jboss/server/dms/deploy/http-invoker.sar/invoker.war

Now it finally gets to the part that has the jar incllude regex

```
List<URL> rawIncludedUrls = urlSet.getUrls();
Set<URL> includeUrls = new HashSet<URL>();
boolean[] patternUsed = new boolean[includeJars.length];

for (URL url : rawIncludedUrls) {
```

since there is the 1 url in the urlset and my jars are not there then it does not find them.  There must be something else I am missing on how to get my url to show up in that url set before the regex comparison code is run,  I just don't know what that is

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what i believe you need to have following in your struts.xml file for Jboss

```
<constant name="struts.convention.exclude.parentClassLoader" value="true" />
```

refer to plugin page for detail [ConventionPlugin-JBoss](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-JBoss).

By default the Convention plugin will not scan jar files for actions. For a jar to be scanned, its URL needs to match at least one of the regular expressions in struts.convention.action.includeJars

You already have list of include jars in your struts.xml.Convention plugin will evaluate regular expression against the URL of the jar, and not the file name.

Comment: I tried that thinking that it would get my jar url, but by the time it looks at the regex for the jars to include it does not have that url in its list of urls to look through.  I have a expanded explanation in my above question with the convention plugin code.